# Stock Charts images dataset

Tags: data-request, api, stock

I try to find a dataset with **stock charts** ... any timeframe and by sec, min, hr or day works for me as well.

So I try to get them simple as possible with minimum indicators on it, candle style.

P.S: did some manual pull of the charts but does include to much indicators and looks like the picture below: [image: sample manual cut of the stock image] and as can be seen the grid, all the numbers on corners, volumes etc I need to have it clear so can't find anything online ... any help on where to get or at least how to get them build manually thru an API will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think an easy way would be [reverse image search](https://www.google.com/search?sa=X&tbs=simg:CAESowIJcYZ4H-E3MQ4alwILEKjU2AQaBAgVCAoMCxCwjKcIGmIKYAgDEijeAs4HuBO2E5EI7gfWAsQH9h_1SAogrlCuJK6Ir8CLvPqUr7iKkK5Y5GjAL741JzITdI9mEzF8pti4sG54cij2ILtFWfrtz6fi8fpdmMQZyUh7kEDfqJEr02NogBAwLEI6u_1ggaCgoICAESBMB-uYkMCxCd7cEJGoIBChoKB2RpYWdyYW3apYj2AwsKCS9tLzAydjBtMgoYCgRwbG902qWI9gMMCgovbS8wNHEzNDd5ChUKA21hcNqliPYDCgoIL20vMDRfdGIKGgoHcGF0dGVybtqliPYDCwoJL20vMDZnMXcyChcKBXNsb3Bl2qWI9gMKCggvbS8wNzhobQw&q=Dow%20Jones%20Industrial%20Average&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwj5uJHBgcHaAhUGhiwKHfwiBZIQsw4IMw&biw=1280&bih=726&dpr=2). You'll get assorted "similar" images, but no clear license. Once you have a folder of images by [scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22871658/2327328), you can manually clean them to include only charts you are looking for. (works for 100s but not 1000s)

[image]

Comment: This type of data I already have but as I stated in the request is way too much indicators inside of each picture, I look only for candle stick line ...